# WebSocketStompClient message on connection event

Tags: spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm trying to connect to my web socket with WebSocketStompClient.

The code of my client looks like this

```
    WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
    container.setDefaultMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE);
    container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE);

    WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient(container);
    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
    StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new SessionHandler();

    StompSession session = null;
    try {
        session = stompClient.connectAsync(URL, sessionHandler).get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        log.error("[runService] ", e);
    }
```

When I look on logs of my web socket I can see this kind of messages:

```
2024-02-05T17:09:21.636Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] r.a.h.config.ServerWebSocketHandler      : [afterConnectionEstablished] f6a64e70-9bfa-0370-1ce4-d16d272b448a
```

By this message my server prints that connection was established.

```
2024-02-05T17:09:21.653Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] r.a.h.config.ServerWebSocketHandler      : [handleTextMessage] f6a64e70-9bfa-0370-1ce4-d16d272b448a, CONNECT
heart-beat:0,0
accept-version:1.1,1.2
```

Next message tells me that my server received message from my client, but as you could see from my code I didn't anything to socket.

I think that it is some kind of default message on connection.

How can I change this message with different content?

For example I want to set this message

```
{"type": "mse", "value": "avc1.640029,avc1.64002A,avc1.640033,hvc1.1.6.L153.B0,mp4a.40.2,mp4a.40.5,flac,opus"}
```